# How to get function return values into ROS topic msg to be published

Tags: c++, ros

I'm a beginner when it comes to working with ROS.
Currently working in Melodic, outside of the catkin workspace. ie: not using catkin

My goal is to create a topic that contains an x and y value, then to update those values from the return value of my path prediction function, which returns a `std::vector<Eigen::Vector2f>` containing the x and y values.

this is what my code looks like:

```
ros::NodeHangle nh;
ros::Publisher topic_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Point>("mytopic/path", 1000);
int counter=0;
ros::Rate rate(10);

while (ros::ok()) {
   geometry_msgs::Point msg;
   msg.data = engine.getPathFunction();
   topic_pub.publish(msg);
   rate.sleep();
   }
```

The line where I set msg.data = engine.getPathFunction(); , returns an error of course.
The return type of getPathFunction() is std::vectorEigen::Vector2f  ... with x and y values for the path.

What's the best way to handle this conversion and get those x and y values into msg?
Is this something ROS can handle? If not, is there another library useful for conversions?
Should I just write my own function? If so, what should that function look like in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best, and only, way to handle this conversion is to do it manually. A `Point` message has fields for `(x,y,z)` so you'll need to simply assign those values yourself. Another thing to note is that a `Point` msg doesn't have a `.data` field like `std_msgs` do.

```
geometry_msgs::Point msg;
std::vector<Eigen::Vector2f> tmp_vec = engine.getPathFunction();
msg.x = tmp_vec[0]; //Assumes x here
msg.y = tmp_vec[1]; //Assumes y here
topic_pub.publish(msg);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do something similar but my ide kept complaining about how .x and .y are appended to 'msg'. Still, this is the correct and best answer. Marked as such. Have a great day!